# How can I access multiple API´s (Facebook and Twitter) on one user?

Tags: php, facebook, oauth, twitter-oauth, facebook-oauth

I am always reading about Facebook and Twitter logins for someones website.
The integration using one of theses services is okay, but my questions is how can I access both API´s for one user.

**Example:**

User is logged in on my website (active session). Now he somehow has to grant me access to his user details etc. on facebook AND twitter. How do I realize that? I don´t want him/her to type in his facebook or twitter credentials everytime he logs in to get his access token (oAuth).
How do I get my own oAuth user access token after using my websites login, so I can interact with Facebook and Twitter´s API.

Is this correct? 
[image: Receive oAuth Token from my website]

Thank you very much, if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

### Facebook

When someone logs into the Facebook account, they stay logged in until they actively log out.

The way to test for this is:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
    if response.status === 'connected'{
        // The user is logged in
        var access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        // Do whatever you need to do
    } else {
        // Get the user to log in
    }
});
```

See here for more details:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

### Twitter

The process is a little more complex for Twitter, but if you only want to display tweets, consider [Web Intents](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents).

Otherwise, follow these steps:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/3-legged-authorization

Both platforms have the ability to check whether or not the user is logged in first, so you shouldn't have to worry about someone having to log in every time they use your site. However, you cannot use the same oAuth token on both sites - you must get a separate one for each.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how come https://ifttt.com/ can use all kind of social media channels without typing in his/her password again.

Comment: Because once an app is authorized, it *stays* authorized until the user de-authorizes it. Likewise, if you log in to a website with Facebook while you are already logged in to Facebook, you do not need to enter your details again - Facebook handles all of that for you. That's what the oAuth tokens are for.

Comment: That is what I was talking about. But the prequiste is that I know which facebook_id , twitter_id is asscociated with my internal user_id? Assume I have internal user_id 1 and facebook id 53432 , which has granted me access to his user details. I can fetch facebook userid´s 53432 data without him logging in to facebook? It actually requires him to be authenticated via oAuth on my page first to work isn´t it like that?

Answer (score 0):

Each individual API will need a popup to authenticate, which will redirect to the appropriate api for authorisation, and then once you have the token after the authorisation redirects back to your popup.

You will then end up with a token that you can pass back to the calling page "window.opener" and store the token for that api in a Javascript variable by alling a Javascript funcation on the main page.

```
window.opener.getInstagramData("self", oauth_token);
```

Each authentication needs to have its own token and needs to be a button that the user should click on.

I am using this method to get Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn Foursquare and GooglePlus account info.

Hope this helps.